# Fixing the Guzzle 400 Bad request for an API error

Tags: php, laravel, api, cross-domain, guzzle

I tried to convert an AJAX API request script into php using Guzzle, however I keep getting a '400 Bad Request' error. The Ajax version works fine.But I'm trying to automate the process in the back end. The script sends a file to the remote API via a 'POST' request and is meant to return a JSON object back which I then save it to a file.

Most of the possible solutions I found(googled for) involved either doing some exception handling or straight deactivating the guzzle errors. None of which worked. I know that the credentials are all correct because I tested with wrong credentials and it returned an authorization error.

This AJAX code works fine, it gets a file from an html form and uploads it to the API server.

```
            $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () { 
                var data = new FormData();
                var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files; 
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
                data.append("audioFiles", files[i]); } 
                data.append("scoresTypes", JSON.stringify([46, 47])); 
                data.append("Flavor", 1);
                data.append("AgentUsername", 'person@email.com');
                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'https://remoteserver.com/api/', 
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username' + ':' + 'password') },
                scoresTypes: "",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,


                success: function (data) { $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data)); } }); 

                ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {  }); 

                }); 
            });
```

This is the PHP code that returns the error '400 Bad Request' to the file

```
public function sendFile($file_path, $file_name){

        $client               = new Client();
        $url                  = 'https://remoteserver.com/api/';
        $credentials          = base64_encode('username:password');
        $audio                = fopen($file_path, 'r');
        $data                 = [];
        $data['audioFiles']    = $audio;
        $data['scoresTypes']   = json_encode([46, 47]);
        $data['Flavor']        = 1;
        $data['AgentUsername'] = 'person@email.com';
        $json_file             = '/path/'.$file_name.'.json';

        try{
            $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$credentials,
                 ],
                'scoresTypes' => '',
                'contentType' => 'false',
                'processData' => false,
                'data'=>$data
            ]);
            $response_s = json_encode($response);
        }
        catch(RequestException $e) {
            $response_s = $e->getResponse()->getBody();
        }

        Storage::disk('disk_name')->put($json_file, $response_s);
```

So this is the output that the PHP function is saving to the file instead of the expected JSON object.

```
{"code":14,"message":"There are no values in scoresTypes or JobTypes keys, please insert valid values in one, or both of them.","responseStatusCode":400}
```

But as you can see the initial data provided to the ajax version seems to be the same as the one I send in the php request.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the Content-Type to multipart/form-data since you are sending files, i think the default header for post request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I'm not a guzzle expert but from what i saw on the examples here you can use something like this instead

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=file#sending-form-files

```php
<?php 
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'field_name',
            'contents' => 'abc'
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'file_name',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'other_file',
            'contents' => 'hello',
            'filename' => 'filename.txt',
            'headers'  => [
                'X-Foo' => 'this is an extra header to include'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```